# Can I make a plugin for Android Studio with Android Studio?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

Can I make a plugin for Android Studio with Android Studio?
Do I have to use IntelliJ to make plugins?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're much better off using IntelliJ. Android Studio doesn't offer any advantages over IntelliJ for doing non-Android development.